# Compare 2 Fingerprint templates generated from mantra scanner

Tags: java, compare, fingerprint, biometrics, image-scanner

I have a Mantra Fingerprint Scanner using which I can store fingerprint details in various formats (i.e. ISO, ANCII, RAW Data). I also stored PNG image from base64 output. Everything is working perfectly.

Now I want to compare fingerprint templates and match them and allocate access to the login page. I searched for many things but did not get anything.

My project platform is Java. I want to compare fingerprint templates using Java.

Answer (score 0):

In order to integrate the Mantra MFS100 fingerprint scanner with a Java application, you will need to use Javascript-supported APIs. One such API is available at https://camsunit.com/product/javascript-api-for-zk-fingerprint-scanner-zk4500-zk9500-MFS100.html.

To implement this integration, you can utilize the scanner directly on the client-side of your application using Javascript. The data captured by the scanner on the client page can then be sent to the server-side (Java component) for further processing and storage.

By following this approach, you can seamlessly communicate between the client-side and server-side components, enabling efficient fingerprint scanning and data handling in your Java application.

Comment: @pravin joshi . How did you save the fingerprint template, please let me know.
For comparing the fingerprints, i have a java code. it might work for you

Answer (score -1):

```
int ret =mfs100.MatchISO(template1,template2);
```

Here, `template1` and `template2` are the templates that you want to compare, and these templates are of ISO1974(2005) works.